# Ember.js: Check if view element is inserted into DOM

Tags: ember.js

In a method on an Ember.View subclass, I would like to make changes to the DOM *only if the view element has already been inserted into the DOM*. How can I check that?

I know I could create an auxiliary property like so:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this.set('elementIsInserted', true);
}
willDestroyElement: function() {
  this.set('elementIsInserted', false);
}
```

But is there some canonical, built-in way?

I didn't find anything skimming [view.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js), but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to set an auxiliary flag, you can extend Ember.View:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
    didInsertElement: function() {
       this.set('elementIsInserted', true);
       this._super();
    },

    willDestroyElement: function() {
       this.set('elementIsInserted', false);
       this._super();
    }
});
```

Now every View that extends Ember.View will get the above.

Also a member of the core team suggested that you avoid referring to `inDOM` as it is an internal variable and not intended to be used in code.

Comment: Thanks! One disadvantage seems to be that now you have to call `this._super()` whenever you declare your own didInsertElement in subclasses of Ember.View.

Comment: So how do you access this from inside your controller? Say I have some code in the controller that I only want ran once the view has been inserted but I don't want that code inside didInsertElement. I would check this flag and put an .observes() on the method to what? Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Every view has a `_state` property, which is set to "inDOM" when the element is inserted.

```
if (this._state=="inDOM") doStuff();
```

should work.  Make sure you have the correct `this`!

Comment: I've marked Zack's answer as accepted because I think it's more "correct", but I'm actually doing this in my own app because it's easier. I'm encapsulating it in a property so it can be easily changed: https://gist.github.com/246bbf7305e09ed7ce80

Comment: The `state` property was renamed to `_state` in Ember 1.6 and the old form has been marked as deprecated in 1.8.